What is the real difference between spin 1/2, spin 1 and spin 2?
I know that spin does not refer to physically spinning like a bicycle wheel, but is more a statement on angular momentum (which also resembles a bicycle wheel).  And I've seen the videos with people twisting their hands to show mobius strips of movement and the spin returning to its original position after one or two twists around. And given that quantum particles are better described as clouds, what is the real difference between spin 1/2, spin 1 and spin 2?  Or perhaps how is each determined?

There are many ways in which these systems are different. First of all, regarding many-body statistics, half-integer spin systems are fermionic while integer spin systems are bosonic. This difference is relevant when it comes to systems of particles, though. For a single particle, the difference in spin tells you a difference in the number of possible polarizations of the particle, of its angular momentum. The possible polarizations go as $2s+1$ where $s$ is the spin, so a spin $0$ particle has one possible polarization, a spin $1/2$ particle has 2, etc.
The spin quantum number, $m_s$ can be measured as either $-1/2$ or $1/2$ for spin $1/2$ particles, as $-1$, $0$ or $1$ for spin $1$ particles, etc. This then relates to the measured angular momentum along a specified direction, multiplying the spin quantum number by $\hbar$.
This is the most obvious difference between particles of different spin. You also mentioned rotations, in this case a particle of spin $s$ will be left in the original state after a rotation of $2\pi/s$ because the spin wave function contains a complex exponential term like
$$e^{is\phi}, $$
so a rotation $2\pi/s$ simply leaves you in a $e^{i2\pi}=1$ state, the original one.

The number of polarizations.  Got it.
